# How to target ALL elements in shadow-root?

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector, shadow-root

I am trying to add a class to an element inside of the shadow root for 3 slides within a carousel. Here is my code:

```js
let modalFlexDisplay = document.querySelector("#ipm-ad-modal-div")
                     .querySelector("#rs-two-col")
                     .shadowRoot.querySelector(".wrapper");

modalFlexDisplay.classList.add("hidden");
```

```html
<div id="ipm-ad-modal-div">
  <div id="rs-two-col">
    <template shadowrootmode="open">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <p>hello and happy halloween</p>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
  <div id="rs-two-col">
    <template shadowrootmode="open">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <p>hello and happy halloween</p>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you inspect the code snippet here, you can see that the class was successfully added to just the first div.wrapper tag. However I want to add them on all, and not just the first one.

When I try to add "querySelectorAll" to any or all of the elements, it returns an error saying it cannot read the properties of querySelector. How do i add the class "hidden" to all elements within each shadow root?

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()` returns a list, so you have to iterate through the list and manipulate the `.classList` of each element individually.

Comment: Also id values must be unique. Your code re-uses "rs-two-col", and that's not OK.

Comment: @MisterJojo sorry I was actually able to access and add a class to the shadow-root if you ran my code you would be able to see. If it was you that gave me a thumbs down, that would be pretty disappointing. My question and description was extremely clear and to the point.

Comment: `shadowrootmode` is non-standard, and you still have 2 elements with the same `id` value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple hurdles, and duplicate IDs is **not** one of them

- `shadowrootmode` is for a Declarative ShadowDOM, not yet supported in FireFox, soon will be
- You don't show any CSS for your `hidden` class. It needs to go *inside* the shadowDOM
- `querySelectorAll` selects multiple elements you have to **loop over** to *dive* into its shadowRoot, then set the `hidden` class

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#subdiv").forEach(subdiv => {
  let shadowdiv = subdiv.shadowRoot.querySelector(".wrapper");
  shadowdiv.classList.add("hidden");
});

// ?? WTF did Microsoft do 25 years ago?
console.log( maindiv );
console.log( subdiv[0] );

// no need for querySelector.. in Chrome and Safari
[...subdiv].forEach( s => s.style.color = "blue" );
```

```html
<div id="maindiv">
  <div id="subdiv" ONE>
    <template shadowrootmode="open">
      <style>
        .hidden { background:red }
      </style>
      <div class="wrapper" >
        <p>hello and happy halloween</p>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
  <div id="subdiv" TWO>
    <template shadowrootmode="open">
      <style>
        .hidden { background:coral }
      </style>
      <div class="wrapper" >
        <p>hello and happy halloween</p>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
```

##### Duplicats IDs

Note duplicate IDs are no issue at all; Microsoft Internet Explorer (then the dominant browser) allowed for duplicates since its first release in the previous century; and every newer browser copied its behavior since.

You *better* not (I never say *should* not) use duplicate IDs because its like calling all your children "X", and that's confusing (unless your first name is Elon)

As you can see in the `console.log` IDs create **global** variables; behavior is slightly different for *duplicate* IDs in FireFox since a FireFox patch in 2017

Interesting to use in test code; but you shouldn't use this in production code... darn I said *should*.. because most of your "experienced" team-members won't have a clue what is going on.

Comment: thank you for this info. very helpful. one question - when you loop over each sub div here: forEach(subdiv => {)); where did you define "subdiv" or how did the machine recognize it?

Comment: see th fine manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach